# LiveData not getting initial call

Tags: android, android-livedata

The docs say that `LiveData#observe` is supposed to get called once when the lifecycle owner goes from inactive to active state. Why does observe never get called when I run the below code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MutableLiveData<String> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        liveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(String s) {
                Log.d("TESTLIVEDATA", "got observer callback");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Subsequent calls to `liveData.setValue("newvalue");` will trigger that observer callback, it's just the initial call that never happens.

Comment: Did the LiveData ever get an initial value (anytime before onStart)?  If not try to call `setValue("")` or even `setValue(null)` inside onCreate

Comment: @RobCo That was why, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the LiveData never had a value set.
If `setValue` has been called once, even before any observer is registered, new observers will see that value once the observer becomes active.

To guarantee new observers get called, call setValue right after creating the LiveData with some initial value, such as `""` or `null`.